# Wrong PID: supervisord program with a Software Collections Python

Tags: centos, python, supervisord, scl

I have a Python server that must be executed by a Software Collections enabled environment.  The `supervisord` config file looks something like this:

```
[program:xxx]
command=/usr/bin/scl enable rh-python35 -- /myenv/bin/python server.py
stdout_logfile=/var/log/xxx.log
redirect_stderr=true
```

The program starts up fine, but `supervisord` thinks that the `scl` process is the actual process, but the **Python server has a different PID**.  When time comes for SIGTERM (stop, restart, etc.), the `scl` process is terminated but the Python server keeps running.

I *could* make my server write a PID file, and then use the `pidproxy` program provided by `supervisord`, as described here:

http://supervisord.org/subprocess.html#pidproxy-program

Then, as described, `supervisord` would send signals to the correct PID.  However, I would prefer, if possible, to avoid changing the server code to create a PID file.

### Question: Is there some other way of setting it up?

Note that directly executing the `python` executable inside the software collection does not work:

```
[user@xxx gpsengine]$ /opt/rh/rh-python35/root/bin/python -V
/opt/rh/rh-python35/root/bin/python: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.5m.so.rh-python35-1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Other details:

- Centos 7

---

EDIT: There is an additional approach besides `pidproxy` which involves an intermediate shell script.  This mailing list entry describes an `enable` *script* (as opposed to the `scl enable` *command*):

https://www.redhat.com/archives/sclorg/2016-June/msg00008.html

This can be used inside a shell script like so:

```
exec 2>&1
test -f /opt/rh/rh-python35/enable && source /opt/rh/rh-python35/enable
exec /myenv/bin/python server.py
```

Since `exec` replaces the shell process, the `supervisord` program config can then point to this shell script as the command.

Comment: Why on earth are you trying to use supervisord?!?

Comment: @MichaelHampton: The existing infrastructure is what it is.

Comment: Someone else's mistake, eh? The proper thing to do is write a systemd unit, of course. Supervisord is obsolete.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: Would the same issue not occur with a systemd unit?  That would be useful information.

Comment: No, systemd understands processes that fork repeatedly.